# Custom error message for carrierwave 0.9.0 doesn't work for Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I use `carrierwave 0.9.0` with Rails 4 and I'm trying to make a custom error message. After doing some search, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784475/setting-custom-error-message-with-carrierwave):

```
en:
  errors:
    messages:
      extension_white_list_error: 'My Custom Message'
```

I tried this by going to `config/locales/en.yml` then adding the code above, but nothing changed. The error message is still the same.

There is also the same issue on github [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1188), but no answers, I think this problem is specific just with Rails 4 but not sure, have you the same problem when you use Rails 4?

Comment: Did you restart your server?

Comment: yes i restart my server but not works

Comment: What is the output of `I18n.t('errors.messages.extension_white_list_error')` ran in rails console?

Comment: it show the original message "You are not allowed to upload %{extension} files, allowed types: %{allowed_types}" :(

Comment: @zrl3dx should i add a specific model to en.yml perhaps ? have you an idea please

Comment: This probably can be done also with overriding specific model messages (`en/activerecord/attributes/model/attribute`), but should be also possible with overriding keys as it is even simpler, can you add some custom key and load it from console? I wonder is it problem with locale (not) loading or with carrierwave's messages as this might be troublesome (at least that's what I've googled).

Comment: i added a key my_error to errors/messages and when i do  I18n.t('errors.messages.my_error') in console it show me what i expect, but why doesn't work with extension_white_list_error key !

Comment: There's even an open issue for that on GH, which version are you using?

Comment: i use version "0.9.0"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38241/discussion-between-medbo-and-zrl3dx)

Answer (score 2):

There seem be some loading issue with Rails 4.0 with regards to i18n files

### Ideally what should be I18n load paths as per 3+

```
/Users/joshianiket22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3_2/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml
/Users/joshianiket22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3_2/gems/activemodel-4.0.0/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml
/Users/joshianiket22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3_2/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/locale/en.yml
/Users/joshianiket22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3_2/gems/actionpack-4.0.0/lib/action_view/locale/en.yml
/Users/joshianiket22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3_2/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/locale/en.yml
/Users/joshianiket22/carrierwave_tester/config/locales/en.yml
```

### What is seen in Rails 4.0

```
/Users/joshianiket22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3_2/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/locale/en.yml
/Users/joshianiket22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3_2/gems/activemodel-3.2.11/lib/active_model/locale/en.yml
/Users/joshianiket22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3_2/gems/activerecord-3.2.11/lib/active_record/locale/en.yml
/Users/joshianiket22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3_2/gems/actionpack-3.2.11/lib/action_view/locale/en.yml
/Users/joshianiket22/workspace/zenjavi/carrierwave_tester/config/locales/en.yml
/Users/joshianiket22/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@rails3_2/gems/carrierwave-0.9.0/lib/carrierwave/validations/../locale/en.yml
```

One can clear see the difference between the two the carrierwave **en.yml** is loaded after a the application specific **en.yml** and there is your issue

I suggest there is no easy way unless you the change the load_paths in rails application and some how manage to change the order of load_paths of as expected

I have given a pull request over [here](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/1229). Completely at awe of Carrierwave guys to decide on it

### Hacky Solution :

I was refraining in giving you this solution earlier but still if you want it that bad here what you can do

define a file in lib directory(let say auto_load_i18n.rb) and assign the lib path to autoload (in **application.rb**)

```
config.autoload_paths += %w(#{config.root}/lib)
```

Inside `auto_load_i18n.rb` write this

```
I18n.load_path.delete(Rails.root.join("config/locales/en.yml").to_s)
I18n.load_path << Rails.root.join("config/locales/en.yml").to_s
```

And require the lib file at the top of your `application_controller.rb`

```
require 'auto_load_i18n'
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

and I guess everything would work then

You can now understand as to why I was refraining in giving this as a possible solution :)

Hope this help

Comment: +1 you are right, yesterday i spend a lot of time in searching and @zrl3dx helps me to discover the same thing, thank you for help, if you find a way to solve this please tell me :)

Comment: Just a hacky solution see if it help you in any case

Comment: thank you @Viren i like your answers, i found already some answers of you in other questions posted by other members and its awesome :) thank a lot for explanation, just for this Hacky Solution i don't know what is bad exactly

Answer (score 1):

It's fixed now guys:

https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/1264

Thanks for the patience.

Answer (score 0):

I use a rails 5.1
I created a file `config/locales/carrierwave.ar.yml` and wrote

```
ar:
  carrierwave:
  errors:
    messages:
      min_size_error: "حجم الصورة لابد أن يكون أكبر من %{min_size}"
      max_size_error: "حجم الصورة لابد أن يكون أقل من %{max_size}"
      ....
```

You can take a look at this [file](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/master/lib/carrierwave/locale/en.yml) :)