# how to upload image in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use actually carrierwave gem as a solution to upload my users photo, but there is a lot of problem with it, and each time i ask a question about it, no one know solution, i asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071739/how-to-validate-size-of-image-with-carrierwave) and another [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19068821/custom-error-message-for-carrierwave-0-9-0-doesnt-work-for-rails-4) and others ... but it seem that people doesn't know a lot of about carrierewave and also documentation is not the place to find solutions.

so what is the best way to upload image in ruby on rails, if also there are a good gem for that which is more clear i will be thankful.

thank you

Comment: 1. It's only been an hour since you asked the question. Be more patient. 2. I added a comment to your other question with some questions that would help others help you. "It doesn't work" helps no one know what's going on. Good luck!

Comment: yes these 2 questions are the question i added today i have other question asked a ... ago ;)

Answer (score 2):

Carrierwave it's a very good gem. I use it in all my projects and I don't remember any concerning issues with it. I think that there is many people knowing a lot about but you have to know that any question, where reproducing problem is needed, especially in specific dependencies version has a longer response time here, than some general issues like 'what gem to the authentication you could recommend'. So being more patient it's the cure for your pains .

Comment: what is rails version are you using ? if rails 4 can you try if customize error messages please

Comment: +1 carrierwave. I personally started with paperclip and found that carrierwave is better in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip might be what you're looking for https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip